# fscanf not scanning file

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I am trying to scan a file using `fscanf` and put the string into an char array of size 20 as follows:

```
char buf[20];
fscanf(fp, "%s", buf);
```

The file `fp` currently contains: `1 + 23`.

I am setting a pointer to the first element in `buf` as follows:

```
char *p;
p = buf;
```

Printing `buf`, `printf("%s", buf)` yields only `1`. Trying to increment `p` and printing prints out rubbish as well (`p++; printf("%c", *p)`).

What am I doing wrong with `fscanf` here? Why isn't it reading the whole string from the file?

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read a line and then, perhaps, `sscanf()` to parse it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fscanf` (and related functions) with the *format-string* "*%s*" will try to read as many characters as it can without including a whitespace, in this case it will find the first character (`1`) and store it, then it will hit a space () and therefore stop searching.

---

If you'd like to read the whole line at once consider using `fgets`, it is also safer to use since you need to specify the size of your destination buffer as one of it's arguments.

`fgets` will try to read at maximum *length-of-buffer minus 1* characters (last byte is saved for the trailing *null-byte*), it will stop at either reading that many characters, hitting a *new-line* or the end of the file.

```
fgets (buf, 20, fp);
```

---

**Links to documentation**

- **[codecogs.com - scanf, fscanf and related functions - <stdio.h>](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/stdio.h/scanf.php)**
- **[codecogs.com - fgets - <stdio.h>](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/stdio.h/fgets.php)**